# Restore bootmgr on encrypted Windows 7 (truecrypt)

Tags: windows-7, restore, truecrypt, disk-encryption, bootmgr

I had Windows 7 and XP on my laptop (win7 had been installed before xp). I encrypted Windows 7 and after that I removed XP. Today truecrypt welcome me with message "bootmgr is missing".

Is it possible to restore win7?